# How to solve this error message if my network is working well

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, network-programming, database-connection

i am trying to reach a network based server program(on visual studio 2013& sql server 2012). On another machine of course. I searched that error and it says my db or server is not open to remote reaches. But i am %100 sure they are reachable.(My program's recent version is also used in my computer and it reaches db and the server.) I am sure my addresses and networks are correct and working. And also checked the ports etc. These were all i could reach. Do you have any other solution or guesses those i can try?
Thanks for your help.

> "ErrorMessage: Server DB ye ulaşamadı(Says server DB is not
>   reachable.) Info:Server - A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server) Yayin OrjErrorMessage: A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

Comment: So one program cant access server but other can? Cant you compare connection parameters or something.

Comment: Yes i would but i only have the .exe of the old program. Where can i see its connection parameters from?

Comment: You can use reflector to analyse exe or you could at least post your current connection code and we will see what you actually have. Now your question is too broad.

Comment: Hey Reniuz after you say, i checked if the other program has a .config file or something like that, i found it have a config file :) i imported it into my code and it worked. And checked that, there was another server also program using. Sorry for taking your time. And thank you for your guide.